# asp.net mvc runtime execution of view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am building a solution where a user can choose the placement of user controls and this layout gets saved in the database. Say the layout is

```
<div>
    <div> 
        {Html.RenderPartial("profileabout");}  
    </div>
    <div>
        {Html.RenderPartial("bloglist");}  
    </div>
</div>
```

Updated : 
I am saving the {Html.RenderPartial("bloglist");}  in the database.

Now, I want to get this layout from database and execute. So all the partial views need to get executed. How can I achieve this?

Comment: To clarify, what are you actually saving to the database? The C# method calls too?

Comment: yes, c# calls too. updated the question.